# How do I set RollingAppender custom file name based on System property

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to change the log file name by modifying the `log4j.xml` to have the appropriate appender.

Here 's a snippet from the `log4j.xml`

```
 <RollingFile name="Rolling-Async-Perf" fileName="/usr/local/mule/logs/${application_name}-weirdo.log"
            filePattern="./logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/perf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz"  immediateFlush="false">
```

Here's how I set the value of `application_name`

```
System.setProperty("application_name", "myAppName");
```

However, the file generated has the name `${application_name}-weirdo.log` rather than `myAppName-weirdo.log`.

Any thoughts on how  I could fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one appender per app or package why dont you hardcode the name in your `fileName` isntead of setting it through System property; which basically signifies all the logs from my *app* go in this *fileName*(hardcoded name).

Anyways; you can see if replacing `${application_name}` with `${sys:application_name}` works for you.